# Serverless framwork error on deploy - Property 'functions[].entrypoint' already have a definition

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm having a problem when deploying a application with aws serverless framework.

**The error message:** *"Property 'functions[].entrypoint' already have a definition - this property might have already been defined by the Serverless framework or one other plugin"*

i've already searched for the error message but found nothing that could help me. I'm using serverless with TypeScript

[this is the serverless.yml configuration and plugins that i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9P2a.png)

[And this is the function configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeIUS.png)

Does anyone know how can i solve this?

I've already tried to use all the functions inside of the `serverless.yml` file and added the following webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.json', '.ts'],
    symlinks: false,
    cacheWithContext: false,
    alias: {
      '@types': path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "@types"),
      libs: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "libs"),
      packages: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "packages")
    }
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false,
    minimize: false,
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [
          [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
          ],
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      eslint: {
        enabled: true,
        files: './src/**/*.ts',
      },
      // eslintOptions: {
      //   cache: true
      // }
    })
  ],
};
```

I have not been able to solve the problem, but i was able to continue with my project by using a template for serverless with TypeScript. This way i was able to complete the deploy.

If you want to, you can find several templates in [this repo](https://github.com/serverless/examples/)

The especific one that i used is [this one](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/v3/aws-node-rest-api-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by just using serverless-webpack in `serverless.yml`. I think the entrypoint is defined first in `serverless-bundle` and then when it tries to set it again in `serverless-webpack` it produces the error